# Draper Decorators and using methods on Application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code in my view that tests if a user is logged in with a method that is on the application controller:

```
def logged_in?
  !!current_user
end
```

I use this method on a view to display certain information only if the user is logged in.

```
<%= **logged_in?** ? link_to('+', upvote_post_path(post), method: 'post', remote: true) : '+' %>
<span id = "post-<%= post.slug %>-votes"> <%= post.total_votes %></span>
```

Now if I want to move this logic to a decorator it won't work because the decorator cannot access this method on the application controller.  I need this to be on there.  So my question is: What is the best way to handle this situation?  The logic can be access from the application helper.  Is there a way that my decorator object access this method without repeating the method twice?

Comment: What are you decorating?

Comment: are you using this gem https://github.com/drapergem/draper, prefix the method call with 'h.' like this h.logged_in?

Comment: Somebody had actually answered this questions a few minutes ago, but the post was deleted.  I'm not sure why... However, the solution was to put the "h" before the method.  In my case it would be "h.logged_in?"  Thanks!

Comment: poorly understood your question and decided that the answer is not correct to confirm the answer if it is correct. thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can access helper `h.some_methods`

```
def link_to_edit_event
   h.link_to h.t('buttons.edit'), h.edit_event_path(id)
end
```

from [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)

> Normal Rails helpers are still useful for lots of tasks. Both Rails'
>   provided helpers and those defined in your app can be accessed within
>   a decorator via the h method:

```
class ArticleDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def emphatic
    h.content_tag(:strong, "Awesome")
  end
end
```